# Klein-Gordon equation probability density and current

Tags: notation

After multiplying the K-G equation and its conjugate by the field, I have this equation

$$\phi^*\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2}- \phi\frac{\partial^2 \phi^*}{\partial t^2}+\phi \nabla^2\phi^*-\phi^* \nabla^2\phi=0 \equiv \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \vec{j}$$

I'm getting

$$\rho = \phi^*\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}- \phi\frac{\partial \phi^*}{\partial t}$$
$$\vec{j} = \phi\nabla\phi^*-\phi^*\nabla\phi$$

I want now to write down the 4-vector current, combining $\rho$ and $\vec{j}$. But the problem is, I don't know how to treat the partial derivatives. Is $\partial / \partial t$ equal to $\partial_0$ or $\partial^0$? Similarly for the spacial part. So if I want to write

$$j^\mu = (\rho,\vec{j})$$

I better have the indices up in the $\rho$ and $\vec{j}$ - but is this the case?

Comment: it depends on your convention for the metric: if you use $(+---)$ then $\partial_t=\partial_0=\partial^0$. If you use $(-+++)$ then $\partial_t=\partial_0=-\partial^0$.

Comment: So $\partial / \partial t$ is always $\partial_0$ and $\partial / \partial x,y,z$ is always $\partial_{1,2,3}$. Ok, that's what I needed to know.

Comment: yep: $x^\mu\equiv (t,\boldsymbol x)$ irrespective of metric conventions. Thus, $\partial_\mu\equiv\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\equiv(\frac{\partial}{\partial t},\nabla)$. If you want to raise/lower indices, you need to say what the metric is: if it is $(+---)$ (usually used in QFT) then $x_\mu=(t,-\boldsymbol x)$; if it is $(-+++)$ (usually used in GR) then $x_\mu=(-t,\boldsymbol x)$.

Answer (score 1):

In general it can be shown that partial derivatives (of both space and time) transform as components of a covariant vector, so the lower subscript (on the partial derivative) is appropriate.